# Applying Security Constraints Liberty for Java

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I have deployed an application to Bluemix, created a Single Sign-in Service, and Bound the service to the application.

The Help Documents tell me I should now...."To complete the configuration of the application, you must add security constraints.."

We do not have anyone with these skills in our organisation, is this something that IBM can help us with? even if its on a billable basis?

Comment: Have you contacted... I dunno... IBM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security constraints are not specific to Liberty or Bluemix. It's a way to define access to url mappings using web.xml.  If you google "Java ee security constraints", you should find a lot of useful information. See [this](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/04/14/easy-single-sign-bluemix-web-applications-using-company-credentials/)  blog post for a basic definition in relation to bluemix.

Comment: Many thanks Ram, the blog post you linked to provides the exact answer I was looking for!